# Multiple constant buffer - register - dx12

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, directx-12

I learn dx12 with that tutorial : 
https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-directx-12-constant-buffers-root-descriptor-tables#c0

I tried to modify this step to got 2 constant buffer (so a register b0 and a b1, if i  understood well).

For that I begin to say in my root sign there is 2 parameters:

```
// create root signature

// create a descriptor range (descriptor table) and fill it out
// this is a range of descriptors inside a descriptor heap
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE  descriptorTableRanges[1]; // only one range right now
descriptorTableRanges[0].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV; // this is a range of constant buffer views (descriptors)
descriptorTableRanges[0].NumDescriptors = 2; // we only have one constant buffer, so the range is only 1
descriptorTableRanges[0].BaseShaderRegister = 0; // start index of the shader registers in the range
descriptorTableRanges[0].RegisterSpace = 0; // space 0. can usually be zero
descriptorTableRanges[0].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND; // this appends the range to the end of the root signature descriptor tables

// create a descriptor table
D3D12_ROOT_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE descriptorTable;
descriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 0;// _countof(descriptorTableRanges); // we only have one range
descriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &descriptorTableRanges[0]; // the pointer to the beginning of our ranges array
D3D12_ROOT_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE descriptorTable2;
descriptorTable2.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;// _countof(descriptorTableRanges); // we only have one range
descriptorTable2.pDescriptorRanges = &descriptorTableRanges[0]; // the pointer to the beginning of our ranges array


// create a root parameter and fill it out
D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER  rootParameters[2]; // only one parameter right now
rootParameters[0].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE; // this is a descriptor table
rootParameters[0].DescriptorTable = descriptorTable; // this is our descriptor table for this root parameter
rootParameters[0].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX; // our pixel shader will be the only shader accessing this parameter for now
rootParameters[1].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE; // this is a descriptor table
rootParameters[1].DescriptorTable = descriptorTable2; // this is our descriptor table for this root parameter
rootParameters[1].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX; // our pixel shader will be the only shader accessing this parameter for now
```

But now I failed to link constant buffer to a variable, I try to modify in this part of the code:

```
 // Create a constant buffer descriptor heap for each frame
// this is the descriptor heap that will store our constant buffer descriptor
for (int i = 0; i < frameBufferCount; ++i)
{
    D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC heapDesc = {};
    heapDesc.NumDescriptors = 1;
    heapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE;
    heapDesc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV;
    hr = device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&heapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mainDescriptorHeap[i]));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        Running = false;
    }
}

// create the constant buffer resource heap
// We will update the constant buffer one or more times per frame, so we will use only an upload heap
// unlike previously we used an upload heap to upload the vertex and index data, and then copied over
// to a default heap. If you plan to use a resource for more than a couple frames, it is usually more
// efficient to copy to a default heap where it stays on the gpu. In this case, our constant buffer
// will be modified and uploaded at least once per frame, so we only use an upload heap

// create a resource heap, descriptor heap, and pointer to cbv for each frame
for (int i = 0; i < frameBufferCount; ++i)
{
    hr = device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD), // this heap will be used to upload the constant buffer data
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, // no flags
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(1024 * 64), // size of the resource heap. Must be a multiple of 64KB for single-textures and constant buffers
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, // will be data that is read from so we keep it in the generic read state
        nullptr, // we do not have use an optimized clear value for constant buffers
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&constantBufferUploadHeap[i]));
    constantBufferUploadHeap[i]->SetName(L"Constant Buffer Upload Resource Heap");

    D3D12_CONSTANT_BUFFER_VIEW_DESC cbvDesc = {};
    cbvDesc.BufferLocation = constantBufferUploadHeap[i]->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    cbvDesc.SizeInBytes = (sizeof(ConstantBuffer) + 255) & ~255;    // CB size is required to be 256-byte aligned.
    device->CreateConstantBufferView(&cbvDesc, mainDescriptorHeap[i]->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());

    ZeroMemory(&cbColorMultiplierData, sizeof(cbColorMultiplierData));

    CD3DX12_RANGE readRange(0, 0);    // We do not intend to read from this resource on the CPU. (End is less than or equal to begin)
    hr = constantBufferUploadHeap[i]->Map(0, &readRange, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&cbColorMultiplierGPUAddress[i]));
    memcpy(cbColorMultiplierGPUAddress[i], &cbColorMultiplierData, sizeof(cbColorMultiplierData));
}
```

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root signature is incorrect, you are trying to set a descriptor table with no range.

You have 3 ways to register a constant buffer in a root signature, with root constants, with a root constant buffer and with descriptor tables. The first two connect one constant buffer per root parameter, while the third allow to set multiple constant buffers in a single table.

In your case, a single root parameter of type descriptor table, with a single range refering to an array of 2 is enough to let you bind 2 constant buffer.

I recommend you to read how [root signatures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn913202(v=vs.85).aspx) are declared in HLSL to better understand the concept and how it translates to the C++ declaration.

As for the runtime portion of manipulating constant buffer. You will have to be very careful again, their is no life time management in d3d12 nor the driver like it was with d3d11, you cannot update in place a constant buffer memory without making sure the GPU is already done using the previous content. The solution is often to work with a ring buffer to allocate your frame constant buffer, and to use fence to keep you from overwriting too soon.

I highly recommend you to stick to d3d11. d3d12 is not a replacement of it, it is made to overcome some of this performance issues that are only to be find in extremely complex renderer and to be used by people with expert knowledge of the GPU already and d3d11, if your application is not to the level of complexity of a GTA V ( just an example ), you are only shooting you in the foot by switching to d3d12.

Comment: Thank, to point those problem and give me the link to HLSL root Signature :)
I don't have this code anymore, I actualy work on that :
https://github.com/Zeldarck/TrainingDx12
But I will back on this problem in the future

I begin the graphic programming, so I know nothing in dx11 too. Thank for the warning but for the moment I prefer continue with dx12 a moment :)

Comment: @Zeldarck It is a very bad idea, but if you stick to it. Read the Microsoft documentation, again and again and avoid tutorials, Learn the documentation to build your own understanding of the API. And in term of danger, pay attention especially to CPU/GPU synchronization and memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem is: You defined 2 pieces of CBV descriptor in one range, and than defined 2 pieces of descriptor table with this range. So , you defined 4 pieces of CBVs instead of 2, and when you define the descriptor heap, you set the heapDesc.NumDescriptors to 1 instead of 4, because you defined 4 constant-buffer descriptor in the code, not 2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).